# How to unclick/unhighlight old feed when clicking new feed in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In my application there are different music categories of which user can choose one type and musics of that specific type are shown. The music categories are shown in a horizontal recyclerview. When one selects a category, that specific category gets highlighted. Now I want to have a code where while the newest feed/ category gets highlighted, at the same time the older selected one gets unhighlighted.

Now I can keep track of the old selected feed with a static integer (say categoryPosition) that stores the position of the feeds being selected. 
Now I cannot find a way in which using the categoryPosition I can track the old feed and unhighlight it, while I am in the itemView of the newest feed.

Here's a little code that is relevant:

```
@Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final CategoryViewHolder viewHolder, final CategoryBlog model, final int position) {

//some other code

viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {



                           //UNHIGHLIGHTING OLD FEED WITH categoryPosition  WHERE I NEED HELP.

                           categoryPosition = position; //set categoryPosition  to newly selected feed.


                        if(model.getName().equals(categorykey))
                        {
                            //highlightening part which I have done successfully
                        }



                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

`LinearLayoutManager` has a method called [`findviewbyposition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#findviewbyposition) that will give you the view associated with `categoryPosition` that you can use to un-highlight the entry. Keep in mind, however, that the view that is being unselected may not be laid out so the return value will be `null`.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful.

Comment: is there any way I can get the layouts/views inside the old category using findviewbyposition (which we usually get in CategoryViewHolder class using itemView.layout_name) ?